# add a builtin function to nodejs

Tags: node.js, require, built-in

I would like to add a couple of functions that we use extensively to nodejs in such a way that they are always available, in the same way as the builtin functions, like Date, Array, Object etcetera.
So without having to do a 'require'.
Is this possible?

gr,

Coen.

Comment: You could use `GLOBAL` object (but you will have to `require` it when your app starting). `GLOBAL.sayHi = function() { console.log('Hi'); }`; once module containing that code `require`d, you can `sayHi()`ing all over you application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack at the [v8 source code](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source) that node.js is based on.

Comment: zi42 is right; it's important to understand that those objects and methods on them are not provided by Node.js; they are provided by the V8 JavaScript engine that Node runs on.